# CakePHP saveAll function redirect doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, redirect

Ik have a problem with the redirect function in cakePHP.
When i use the saveAll

```
if($this->Invoice->save($this->request->data)){
        $this->Session->setFlash('Factuur is opgeslagen.');
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Clients','action'=>'index'));
```

the saveAll works but when he redirects i get a white page.
Does someone has the answer?

Comment: What's the level of debug in `/app/Config/core.php`? Could you set it to 2. Also, is there code in the `index()` method of the ClientsController?

Comment: "I get a white page" usually has something to do with having whitespace in a PHP file before the `<?php` or after the `?>`

Comment: Thanks it was the whitespace after the ?> thanks everyone

Comment: This is why all CakePHP files leave out the closing `?>` tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: $this->redirect('/Clients/index');